# C++ checksum reading nonexistent newline

Tags: c++, checksum

I am doing a very basic checksum on files by reading the input file into a character array, and then iterating over that array and adding each character into the checksum. The problem is that when I do this all of my checksums are 10 too high (10 is the ascii decimal value for the newline character).

How is it newline characters are being inserted into my code, when I know for a fact there is no newline character in my text? Even a single line text file gets a newline character added in!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main () {
    int fileLength = 0;
    std::ifstream inputFile;
    char charArray[10000];
    int checkSumValue = 0;

    // open file in binary
    inputFile.open("/Path/To/File", std::ios::binary);

    // get file length, then return to beginning of file
    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    fileLength = inputFile.tellg();
    inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    // read all data from file into char array
    inputFile.read(charArray, fileLength);

    // iterate over char array, adding ascii decimal value to checksum
    for (int num = 0; num <= fileLength; num++) {
        std::cout << "Checksum value before iteration " << num << " is " 
        << checkSumValue << std::endl;
        checkSumValue += static_cast<int>(charArray[num]);
    }

    // properly close out the input file
    inputFile.close();
    inputFile.clear(std::ios_base::goodbit);  

    std::cout << "The checksum value is: " << checkSumValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The file length is: " << fileLength << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
num <= fileLength
```

It should be:

```
num < fileLength
```

For example. If the length is 1. Then the only valid character is `charArray[0]`

Also note. Doing this:

```
inputFile.read(charArray, fileLength);
```

is dangerious as `fileLength` may be larger than the size of the array.
A better solution would be to use a vector (as it dynamically sizes)

```
std::vector<char>   charArray(fileLength);
inputFile.read(&charArray[0], fileLength);
```

But do you really need to copy the data into an array? Why not just do the sum on the fly.

```
size_t checkSumValue = std::accumulate(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fileLength),
                                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                                       size_t(0)
                                      );
```

Comment: Ahh, but here is the thing: I am showing a length of 3 on a file with just two characters: `At`. Even after changing the for loop to `num < filelength` I am still seeing the newline char being added in. The only way to remove it is by changing my code to `num < filelength - 1`. However, I don't know if what I'm seeing is platform independent, so I may be breaking my app in windows by adding this code.

Comment: @Martin: you should also never read the entire file into memory. What would happen if you opened a 10G data file? Read the file in small blocks.

Comment: @Moses: If it says the file length is 3 then there are three characters in the file. (0, 1, 2) Check out the file with another tool to validate but there are three characters in the file.

Comment: @Martin I've tried creating text files using the terminal `cat >> newfile` command, I've tried creating files in vim `vim newfile`, and I've tried creating files in TextWrangler. All three result in reading two characters as three, and calculate an erroneous extra line... but since you aren't seeing this and since I doubt vim and cat are adding any overhead, I'm going to assume that this is a bug with xcode since my code worked for you.

Comment: @Moses: It is not XCode. XCode is just an environment that uses a normal compiler. Try from the command line `wc -c <fileName>` this will tell you how many characters in the file.  Try this for making a file with 2 characters `echo -n AT > <filename>`

Answer (score 1):

Martin was also correct - you should be (num < fileLength) in all cases.

The other possibility is that you created your file in an editor and it's artificially added a spurious newline for you. That's common. Try dumping your file in a hex editor. I just ran your program (with the <= removed) and it works fine.